# Why are all elements printed although they are the same in mapWithState

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm sending 3 times the same object to JavaPairDStream. I'm updating it's state but it's saved 3 times. Printing the JavaPairDStream confirms this.

```
Function3<InputMessageKey, Optional<InputMessage>, State<InputMessage>, Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>> mappingFunction = new Function3<InputMessageKey, Optional<InputMessage>, State<InputMessage>, Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage> call(InputMessageKey key, Optional<InputMessage> value, State<InputMessage> state) {
            InputMessage inputMessage = value.get();
            Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage> output = new Tuple2<>(key, inputMessage);
            state.update(inputMessage);
            return output;
        }
    };
```

Printing the stream:

```
(com.input.InputMessageKey@220593a0,com.input.InputMessage@781bfd72)
(com.input.InputMessageKey@220593a0,com.input.InputMessage@781bfd72)
(com.input.InputMessageKey@220593a0,com.input.InputMessage@781bfd72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not saved three times. You're returning the `Tuple2` object you've created at the end of the function, and that is what's being printed out. If you want to see the internal state that's saved, use [`JavaMapWithStateDStream.stateSnapshots`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaMapWithStateDStream) in your graph instead iterating the output of `mapWithState`.